# I can't change the shape of the numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I can't change shape of numpy array

```
dataset[i].shape   # (1134, )
dataset[i] = dataset[i].reshape((18, 63))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (18,63) into shape (1134)
```

Comment: The reshaping worked; the problem is you cant set a row of a matrix to a reshaped numpy array (which is what you are trying to do with `dataset[i] = ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what your original intentions are, but your code is attempting to do an element-by-element assignment, between an array on the LHS and an array on the RHS.

The array on the LHS is `dataset[i]`, which has shape `(1134,)`.

The array on the RHS has shape `(18,63)`, due to the (successful) `reshape()`.

In this kind of elemen-by-element assignment, either the LHS array and RHS array need to have the same shape, or the RHS array should be broadcastable into the shape of the LHS array. It so happens that, by the [rules of broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html#basics-broadcasting), shape `(18,63)` cannot be broadcast into shape `(1163,)`. That's the reason behind the error message.

The title of your question says "I can't change the shape of numpy array", but that is not what your code is attempting to do.

If, for some reason, you thought you could change the shape of `dataset[i]`, rather than change the shape of `dataset`, and if that was the original intention behind your code, that is not possible -- you cannot change the shape of a slice of an array.

Even if you do `dataset.reshape(-1, 18, 63)`, that won't change the shape of `dataset` **"in-place"**. Instead, `dataset.reshape(-1, 18,63)` will return a new numpy array with the specified shape, which happens to be a **view** into `dataset` (it uses the underlying data of `dataset`).